# C Carriage Return: Changing Output Like apt-get

Tags: c, carriage-return

In some Linux-based operating systems (like Ubuntu) you can download from the internet within Terminal using the `apt-get` command. When you download something, it shows how much of the package has been downloaded as a percentage. This percentage changes as the package downloads. How can I make a C program behave in a similar way? This is my code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(){
    int i = 0;
    for (; i < 10; i++){
        printf("\rCalculating...%d%%",i);
        usleep(500000);
    }
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
```

I use `gcc` to compile it but instead of getting `Calculating...1%`, `Calculating...2%`, etc. in the output like I expected, nothing appears. After a couple seconds the only output is `Calculating...9%\n`. None of the numbers in between are shown. Why is this?

Comment: so you want download package from `C`?

Comment: @Jayesh I want my program to _behave_ like `apt-get` (`Calculating...1%` then `2%` then `3%` etc). This is just an example, I'm going to use this to show something more meaningful.

Comment: E.g. `wget` (and I think, `apt-get` as well) outputs its progress to `stderr` which is unbuffered. Depending on what you do, this might be a better approach. E.g. I sometimes do `wget example.com -O - | some_other_prog` and pipe the downloaded file to another program and the progress bar is still on my terminal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, add a fflush(stdout) after every printf to force the flshing

Comment: That was fast... I can't even accept the answer yet XD

Answer (score 0):

strange ... i run it on ideone.com and your code worked fine this is the output i got:

```
Calculating...0%
Calculating...1%
Calculating...2%
Calculating...3%
Calculating...4%
Calculating...5%
Calculating...6%
Calculating...7%
Calculating...8%
Calculating...9%
```

so it is what it should be ... i'll try to look into that when i got time

Comment: did you add a `\n` at the end of the printf?

Comment: then I don´t understand the new line after each %

Comment: @mch maybe since the code was run on a website the new line is added automatically

Comment: yeah probably that's the case